# Why does this code work successfully with Enumerator.fromFile?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I wrote the file transferring code as follows:

```
val fileContent: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.fromFile(file)
val size = file.length.toString
file.delete // (1) THE FILE IS TEMPORARY SO SHOULD BE DELETED 
SimpleResult(
 header = ResponseHeader(200, Map(CONTENT_LENGTH -> size, CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/pdf")),
 body = fileContent)
```

This code works successfully, even if the file size is rather large (2.6 MB),
but I'm confused because my understanding about .fromFile() is a wrapper of fromCallBack() and SimpleResult actually reads the file buffred,but the file is deleted before that.

MY easy assumption is that java.io.File.delete waits until the file gets released after the chunk reading completed, but I have never heard of that process of Java File class,
Or .fromFile() has already loaded all lines to the Enumerator instance, but it's against the fromCallBack() spec, I think.

Does anybody knows about this mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are on some kind of a Unix system, OSX or Linux for example.

On a Unix:y system you can actually delete a file that is open, any filesystem entry is just a link to the actual file, and so is a file handle which you get when you open a file. The file contents won't become unreachable /deleted until the last link to it is removed.

So: it will no longer show up in the filesystem after you do file.delete but you can still read it using the InputStream that was created in Enumerator.fromFile(file) since that created a file handle. (On Linux you actually can find it through the special /proc filesystem which,  among other things, contains the filehandles of each running process)

On windows I think you will get an error though, so if it is to run on multiple platforms you should probably check test your webapp on windows as well.